# question about currents

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I have a question in the field of currents:
Let M be an n-dimensional smooth manifold, and let T be a k-current (induced by a k dimensional sub-manifold), I would like to approximate it by a series of continuous k-currents that are induced by smooth k-forms.
I tried to look in a few books about it, including de Rham and Krantz. But since my background in functional analysis is not too wide it was a bit hard for me. I also tried to write the current as a sum of distributions but didn't succeed. I hope someone can help me or give me a reference to a source that will do so.

Comment: In Euclidean space (or more generally, on a Lie group) use convolution. Globally, use a partition of unity to reduce to a local problem.

Comment: For reference, this kind of smoothing (or regularization) of currents is the content of Thm.12 in §15 of de Rham's 1955 treatise, which is handled exactly as Ben McKay suggests.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have reference to concrete where a use in this technique was made? I tried de Rham book but not sure I fully understood.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine regarding applications, what about that paper by Dennis Sullivan you told me about a while ago (*Cycles for the Dynamical Study of Foliated Manifolds and Complex Manifolds*, Invent. Math. **36** (1976) 225-255)? The elements of the approximating sequence are called therein "diffuse currents". De Rham's result is given a brief sketch of proof in pp. 233-234.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro, yes, I guess that would be an application of the smoothing idea (though a rather advanced one). Perhaps a more common one is the construction of a $k$-form that is Poincaré dual to a codimension-$k$ submanifold. For the record, I do think that de Rham does a good job of introducing smoothing. One other references is Secs.4.1.2--4 in Federer's _Geometric Measure Theory_, but I'm not sure that they do a better job.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine ah yes, good point, although the application you suggest seems to be more easily accomplished by means of a generator of the Thom class of the normal bundle to the submanifold and a tubular neighborhood of the latter (as done e.g. in Bott-Tu). It's possible that similar ideas underlie both approaches, but I'm not seeing that right now. (it's a bit late here, though...)